# Grails domain class unit test errors

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I wrote the following domain class with its unit test. When I run the tests, I get the error message
`No such property: admittedMobileUser`. When I comment that line in domain class I get the same problem on other fields. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

```
class MobileUser {
    String userName
    String userDevice="Android"
    Integer userCluster
    Boolean admittedMobileUser
    Date lastTimeUpdatedUserSpaceTime=new Date()
    byte[] userSpaceTimeXml

    static constraints = {
        userName blank:false, unique:true
        userDevice blank:false
        userCluster validator : {val-> return val > 0}
        admittedMobileUser
        lastTimeUpdatedUserSpaceTime
        userSpaceTimeXml maxSize:1024*1024
    }

    String toString(){
        return "${userName}_${userCluster}"
    }

}
```

Comment: When you commented it out, did you also comment it out of the constraints?

Comment: yes I did, and I did the test unit to simple one to make sure its correct. (just assert true)

Comment: class MobileUserTests {

    void testSomething() {
       assert true
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove such rows from constraints :

```
    ....
    admittedMobileUser
    lastTimeUpdatedUserSpaceTime
    ....
```

or add minimum one constraint to each!

Comment: Your solution is also working. I changed admittedMobileUser---admittedMobileUser() and lastTimeUpdatedUserSpaceTime-->lastTimeUpdatedUserSpaceTime(). It's now working!